# Grouped sorting of continuous paragraphs (separated by blank line)?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I think I'm pretty experienced now in sorting by *columns*; however, I haven't found anything so far how to sort *continuous rows*.

Supposing we have a text file that looks like this: (very simplified, of course)

```
Echo
Alpha
Delta
Charlie

Golf
Bravo
Hotel
Foxtrot
```

Now, is it possible to sort the lines alphanumerically *per each block separately*?
I mean, so that the result looks like this:

```
Alpha
Charlie
Delta
Echo

Bravo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
```

Telling from what I found in the `sort` man page, this might not be possible with the built-in UNIX `sort`command. Or can it even be done without having to resort to external/third-party tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drav's `awk` solution is good, but that means running one `sort` command per paragraph. To avoid that, you could do:

```
< file awk -v n=0 '!NF{n++};{print n,$0}' | sort -k1n -k2 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Or you could do the whole thing in `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\S/){push@l,$_}else{print sort@l if@l;@l=();print}
          END{print sort @l if @l}' < file
```

Note that above, separators are blank lines (for the `awk` one, lines with only space or tab characters, for the `perl` one, any horizontal or vertical spacing character) instead of empty lines. If you do want empty lines, you can replace `!NF` with `!length` or `$0==""`, and `/\S/` with `/./`.

Comment: Thanks to you too, especially for the `awk` solution which avoids the `sort` overhead! Sneaky!

Answer (score 10):

```
awk -v RS= -v cmd=sort '{print | cmd; close(cmd); print ""}' file
```

Setting the record separator `RS` to an empty string makes awk step in paragraphs at a time.
For each paragraph, pipe the paragraph (in `$0`) to cmd (which is set to `sort`) and print the output. Print out a blank line to separate the output paragraphs with a `print ""`.

If we're giving perl examples, then I present an alternative approach than that of Stephane's:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; print join "\n", sort (split /\n/), "\n" 
    foreach(split(/\n\n/, <>))' < file
```

Unset the field separator (`undef $/`), this allows us to use `<>` and get the whole of STDIN. We then `split` that around `\n\n` (paragraphs). `foreach` "paragraph", `sort` the lines by `split`ting around newlines, `sort`ing and then `join`ing them back together and tacking on a trailing `\n`.

However, this has one side effect of adding a "trailing paragraph" separator on the last paragraph (if it didn't have one before). You can get around that with the slightly less pretty:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; print join "\n", sort (split /\n/) , (\$_ == \$list[-1] ? "" : "\n")
    foreach(@list = split(/\n\n/, <>))' < file
```

This assigns the paragraphs to `@list`, and then there is a "ternary operation" to check if it is the last element of the `foreach` (the `\$_ == \$list[-1]` check). print `""` if it is (`? ...`), else (`: ...`) print `"\n"` for all other "paragraphs" (elements of `@list`).

Comment: This is neat! Thank you. Are you actually invoking `/usr/bin/sort` with that line or is it an `awk` built-in "sort" command?

Comment: Invoking the sort command, hence the requirement to close(cmd) on each loop :)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a tool in haskell that allows you to use sort, shuf, tac or any other command on paragraphs of text.

https://gist.github.com/siers/01306a361c22f2de0122
EDIT: the tool is also included in this repo: https://github.com/siers/haskell-import-sort

It splits the text into blocks, joins the subblocks with `\0` char, pipes through the command and finally does the same thing in reverse.

**28-08-2015**: I found an other, personal use for this tool — selecting N paragraphs after a line.

```
paramap grep -aA2 '^reddit usernames' < ~/my-username-file
reddit usernames

foo
bar
baz

a couple
more of these
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU awk available you could sort each block using the built-in `asort()` function. Something like this:

*blocksort.awk*

```awk
function sort_n_print(array) {
  asort(array)
  for(i=1; i<=length(array); i++)
    print array[i]
  delete array
}

NF { a[++x] = $0 }

!NF { sort_n_print(a); print }

END { sort_n_print(a) }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f blocksort.awk infile
```

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html) Lisp step by step:

```
$ cat data
Echo
Alpha
Delta
Charlie

Golf
Bravo
Hotel
Foxtrot

$ txr -p '(get-lines)' < data
("Echo" "Alpha" "Delta" "Charlie" "" "Golf" "Bravo" "Hotel" "Foxtrot")

$ txr -t '(get-lines)' < data
Echo
Alpha
Delta
Charlie

Golf
Bravo
Hotel
Foxtrot

$ txr -p '(partition* (get-lines) (op where [chain length zerop]))' < data
(("Echo" "Alpha" "Delta" "Charlie") ("Golf" "Bravo" "Hotel" "Foxtrot"))

$ txr -p '[mapcar sort (partition* (get-lines) (op where [chain length zerop]))]' < data
(("Alpha" "Charlie" "Delta" "Echo") ("Bravo" "Foxtrot" "Golf" "Hotel"))

$ txr -p '(interpose (list "") [mapcar sort (partition* (get-lines) (op where [chain length zerop]))])' < data
(("Alpha" "Charlie" "Delta" "Echo") ("") ("Bravo" "Foxtrot" "Golf" "Hotel"))

$ txr -t '(interpose (list "") [mapcar sort (partition* (get-lines) (op where [chain length zerop]))])' < data
Alpha
Charlie
Delta
Echo

Bravo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
```

References: [get-lines](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-00391A9C), [partition*](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-034EFB7A), [op](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01076097), [where](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0188CFC0), [chain](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-026521E5), [length](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02621D68), [zerop](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-013904E7), [mapcar](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000FB858), [interpose](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-03F4714C).

Comment: Note that in the `[mapcar sort ...]` we could replace `sort` by a function which pipes the strings through an external process. We can then end up with a tool for distributing a text processing external command over paragraphs.